# Can you read the HttpsError status of a firebase function?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I have a firebase function in which I manually throw an error with a status and message like this:

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Token does not match');
```

The response I get from the server looks like this (using chrome dev console):

```
{"error":{"message":"Token does not match","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

But when I call the function like this, the error does not have a status in it (using AngularFire2):

```
try {
    return await this.functions.httpsCallable<void, void>('testFunc')().toPromise();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.name); // "Error"
    console.log(e.message); // "Token does not match"
    console.log(e.status); // undefined
}
```

Is there any way to get the status of it, because I would rather check for `if(e.status == 'PERMISSION_DENIED')` than `if(e.message == 'Token does not match')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is going to be a [HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.HttpsError) object.  As you can see from the API docs, it should have a property called `code` which is a [FunctionsErrorCode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions#functionserrorcode) object that contains the HTTP status code as a string that should match what you threw from the callable function.  So I would expect `e.code` to be the string `permission-denied`.

Comment: Can we see an example of how to use FunctionsErrorCode constants (with import) I'm unable to find them on the import and references.